# Azure app service scale up or scale out for function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have function app which process XML files from Azure blob and put the data in Azure SQL DB. This is working fine when the Size of the file is in kb ( we have told the sender to send the file up to 100kb).

The problem comes when the file size increases to “2MB to 3MB”. The problem is it gets stuck in middle of processing and as the job runs in every 2hours, the blob receives files in every 2 hours - then everything stuck ( the current processing files and the new files as well )

I can’t change the schedule from 2hours to more. considering this, Is there anyway to scale up or scale out the app service plan so that it can process the larger size in 2hours time? Will there be a code or configuration change required for this ? Also, if yes, what is the costing plan for this?

Or, is there any other way to handle such situations?

Please note, the current app service plan is S2:2 and all deployment slots are in same app service plan.

Comment: have a look at the azure functions hosting options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: What do your Metrics say? Is the CPU or some other metrics peaking? You can consider moving to a P1V2 or P1V3. It is cheaper for Linux as compared to Windows. You can use the Azure pricing calculator to calculate your cost https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator

Comment: Look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up on how to scale up your app service. Its only a config change. No changes needed. Please be aware of the costs associated with your new instance before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Roman Kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8084828/roman-kiss) and [Anupam Chand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14358677/anupam-chand). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

The hosting plan you choose dictates the following behaviors:

- How your function app is scaled.
- The resources available to each function app instance.
- Support for advanced functionality, such as Azure Virtual Network connectivity.

[image]

Check [Hosting Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) for further information.

Here is the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) for moving P1V2 to P1V3.

Below image will help you in scaling up your app service
[image]

If you app depends on other services like SQL and Storage you need to Scale up these resources separately.

[image]

In the Resource Group link go to summary and select the resource to scale up.

[image]

For further information click [Scale up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up#scale-up-your-pricing-tier) in Azure App Service.